# SQL Select multiple joins and MAX(field) result

Tags: sql, sql-server, cognos

I'm using IBM Cognos to create a report which allows for fairly standard SQL.  I am ultimately trying to take data from 2 tables and compare them to each other to ensure they match.  Billing_Term, Bill_Period and Contract_Term_Amount all need to match when comparing a given Contract_Number, Contract_Item and Stream_Type between t1 and t3 but only for the MAX Seq_No from t3.

I tried a simple MAX() on Seq_No but that didn't work so I'm looking for help in limiting the results to the MAX Seq_No for the associated query results.

```
    SELECT
        t1.Contract_Number, 
        t1.Contract_Item, 
        t1.Stream_Type, 
        t1.Billing_Term, 
        t1.Bill_Period, 
        t1.Contract_Term_Amount,
        t2.Reference_Document,
        t3.Billing_Term,
        t3.Bill_Period,
        t3.Contract_Term_Amount,
        t3.Seq_No
    FROM
        LeasingStreamData t1 
    INNER JOIN ContractsData t2 ON t1.Contract_Number = t2.Sales_Document
    LEFT JOIN LeasingStreamData t3 ON t2.Reference_Document = t3.Contract_Number AND
        t1.Contract_Item = t3.Contract_Item AND
        t1.Stream_Type = t3.Stream_Type
    WHERE 
    t1.Contract_Number IN ([some list of contracts])
    GROUP BY 
        t1.Contract_Number, 
        t1.Contract_Item, 
        t1.Stream_Type, 
        t1.Billing_Term, 
        t1.Bill_Period, 
        t1.Contract_Term_Amount,
        t2.Reference_Document,
        t3.Billing_Term,
        t3.Bill_Period,
        t3.Contract_Term_Amount,
        t3.Seq_No
```

I hope this is enough to get some much needed help, many thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: my actual query doesn't use t1, t2 etc... i changed that to try and simplify the code.  ironically, i then get a link to a document requesting i do just that.

Comment: Since this is for Cognos, it would have been more straight-forward to provide the report spec from a simple report developed using the sample data.  GO Sales (query) is the package I always use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you requirement, I think you want to create queries and join them in a way that will look like this SQL:

```
SELECT
  t1.Contract_Number
, t1.Contract_Item
, t1.Stream_Type
, t1.Billing_Term
, t1.Bill_Period
, t1.Contract_Term_Amount
, t2.Reference_Document
, t3.Billing_Term
, t3.Bill_Period
, t3.Contract_Term_Amount
, t3.Seq_No

FROM (
    SELECT Contract_Number
    , Contract_Item
    , Stream_Type
    , Billing_Term
    , Bill_Period
    , Contract_Term_Amount
    FROM LeasingStreamData
    WHERE Contract_Number in ([some list of contracts])
  ) t1 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Sales_Document
    , Reference_Document
    FROM ContractsData
    WHERE Sales_Document in ([some list of contracts])
  ) t2 ON t1.Contract_Number = t2.Sales_Document
  INNER JOIN LeasingStreamData t3 ON t2.Reference_Document = t3.Contract_Number 
                               AND t1.Contract_Item = t3.Contract_Item 
                               AND t1.Stream_Type = t3.Stream_Type
  INNER JOIN (
      select max(Seq_No) as Seq_No
      , Contract_Number
      , Contract_Item
      , Stream_Type
      from LeasingStreamData lsd
      group by Contract_Number
      , Contract_Item
      , Stream_Type
  ) maxseq on maxseq.Contract_Number = t3.Contract_Number
          and maxseq.Contract Item = t3.Contract_Item
          and maxseq.Stream_Type = t3.Stream_Type
          and maxseq.Seq_No = t3.Seq_No

WHERE t1.Billing_Term <> t3.Billing_Term
  and t1.Bill_Period <> t3.Bill_Period
  and t1.Contract_Term_Amount <> t3.Contract_Term_Amount

GROUP BY 
  t1.Contract_Number
, t1.Contract_Item
, t1.Stream_Type
, t1.Billing_Term
, t1.Bill_Period
, t1.Contract_Term_Amount
, t2.Reference_Document
, t3.Billing_Term
, t3.Bill_Period
, t3.Contract_Term_Amount
, t3.Seq_No
```

I think this will filter to only the max Seq_No for t3 and return only the records that you care about (the ones that don't match).

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar. However, your code isn't quite right. Your subselect will throw an error because you have an aggregate column combined with non-aggregate columns without a group by function. Should be ``select max(Seq_No) as Seq_No
      , Contract_Number
      , Contract_Item
      , Stream_Type
      from LeasingStreamData group by Contract_number,Contract_Item,Stream_type``  There are other optimizations to be had as well but hopefully he gets the gist.

Comment: Thanks.  Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: many thanks dougp and Johnsonium, i will try this out and let you know

Comment: wanted to confirm this got me what i needed, thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Contract_Number
    ,t1.Contract_Item
    ,t1.Stream_Type
    ,t1.Billing_Term
    ,t1.Bill_Period
    ,t1.Contract_Term_Amount
    ,t2.Reference_Document
    ,t3.Billing_Term
    ,t3.Bill_Period
    ,t3.Contract_Term_Amount
    ,t3.Seq_No
FROM LeasingStreamData t1
INNER JOIN ContractsData t2 ON t1.Contract_Number = t2.Sales_Document
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Contract_Number
        ,Contract_Item
        ,Stream_type
        ,MAX(Seq_No) AS "Seq_No"
    FROM LeasingStreamData
    GROUP BY Contract_Number
        ,Contract_Item
        ,Stream_Type
    ) t3 ON t2.Reference_Document = t3.Contract_Number
    AND t1.Contract_Item = t3.Contract_Item
    AND t1.Stream_Type = t3.Stream_Type
WHERE t1.Contract_Number IN ([some list of contracts])
```

Since the rollup for the aggregate function (MAX) relies on the group by to determine context, you have to isolate it via a subquery to get the max before joining to the rest of the tables.

Also, since you are preaggregating the max sequence number, you no longer need a group by in the main query.